# Form doesn't validate when passing form value to the next view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

In my index view I have a ModelChoiceField which allows me to choose various equipments.

When I have submitted my choice, I keep the selected value in a variable like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    request.session["eq"] = form.cleaned_data['equipment']
```

Then I am redirected to a new view(reservation) in which I have a form with three fields: "equipment", "date" and "reserved_by". Since I have already chosen the equipment i want in the previous view I want it to be filled in automatically. I managed this by doing the following in my reservation view:

```
form = ReservationForm(initial={'equipment': request.session.get('eq')})
```

So when I run my site, the equipment field in the reservation view does get automatically filled in, but now the form suddenly won't validate(form.is_valid is false).

Been struggling with this for a while now so any help would be highly appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This form from your question is unbound.

```
form = ReservationForm(initial={'equipment': request.session.get('eq')})
```

Unbound forms are never valid. To get a valid form, you need to bind it to post or get data.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but how do I do that? Or is there an easier way to pass a value from one form to another?